# jshell continues executing my script after exception is thrown. How to make it stop?

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I tried writing some jshell scripts. When an exception is thrown, jshell still goes on to execute the next line.

How can I make my scripts behave more like normal java programs?

***Edit***: I simply run it like `jshell SCR.jsh`.

Using `throw new Exception()` or `1/0` does not prevent the next line from being executed.

The script includes statement like this:

```
System.out.println(1/0)
System.out.println("foo")
/exit
```

I thought the second line is unreachable. That's what I expected. But after the exception is printed, `foo` is also printed.

Comment: This question would benefit from an example that demonstrates the behavior in question.

Comment: It would be good to look at a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the issue.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my understanding, the reason why `jshell` executes all the lines in your script even after one throws an Exception is since it treats your script as a *list of [`Snippet`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/Snippet.html).*

> All expressions are accepted as snippets. This includes expressions
>   without side effects, such as constants, variable accesses, and lambda
>   expressions:
>
> ```
> 1
> a
> x -> x+1
> (String s) -> s.length()
> ```
>
> as well as expressions with side effects, such as assignments and
>   method invocations
>
> ```
> System.out.println("Hello world");
> new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
> ```

So even one of the snippet throws an exception, the others must follow the ***[Read-Eval-Print Loop](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222)***(REPL) pattern. As also [answered yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46358058/1746118) converting the code as a block of statement marks it as a single `Snippet` which when throws the `java.lang.ArithmeticException` marks its completion thereby.

Though ideally, such statements should be instead defined as a *declaration snippet*.

> A declaration snippet (`ClassDeclaration`, `InterfaceDeclaration`,
>   `MethodDeclaration`, or `FieldDeclaration`) is a snippet that explicitly
>   introduces a name that can be referred to by other snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I think I found a workaround:

```
{
    System.out.println(1/0);
    System.out.println("foo");
}
/exit
```

Now it's much closer to the familiar java code.

Not only exception works just as expected, but semicolons also become necessary inside the block.